# logstash multiline filter for asterisk

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

# Logstash configuration problem

My actual logfile looks like:

> INFO - 2015-06-22 06:55:11 - \n**********************************************************************************\n********* XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2015-06-22 06:55:11\n********** Time zone is Pacific Standard Time or America/Los_Angeles\n**********************************************************************************\n\n\nINFO - 2015-06-22 06:55:32 - Finished loading connector modules

On logstash I applied the multiline filter

```
 multiline {
        pattern => "%{LOGLEVEL}"
        what => "next"
        negate => true
        }
```

I expected the output

1.

> INFO - 2015-06-22 06:55:11 - \n**********************************************************************************\n********* XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2015-06-22 06:55:11\n********** Time zone is Pacific Standard Time or America/Los_Angeles\n**********************************************************************************

2.

> INFO - 2015-06-22 06:55:32 - Finished loading connector modules

But I am getting the result as

1. > INFO - 2015-06-22 06:55:11 -

2.

> \n**********************************************************************************\n********* XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2015-06-22 06:55:11\n********** Time zone is Pacific Standard Time or America/Los_Angeles

3.

> \n**********************************************************************************\n\n\nINFO - 2015-06-22 06:55:32 - Finished loading connector modules

Can anyone suggest where am I going wrong with the multiline pattern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your config says, "unless the line contains LOGLEVEL, keep it with the next line".

You need "previous", and "starts with LOGLEVEL" wouldn't hurt.